# Trying to load video through javascript

Tags: javascript, video, server

I want to dynamically load videos from a server to a client using javascript DOM manipulation. I tried this code but the callback function onload doesn't run and in addition in the network tab in the request headers accept field is "/".

```
function doAjaxVideo(param, lambda) {
    let video = document.createElement("video");
    let sourceElem = document.createElement("source");
    sourceElem.src = param;
    sourceElem.type = "video/webm";
    video.appendChild(sourceElem);
    video.autoplay = "true";
    video.onload = () => lambda();
}

doAjaxVideo("/video.webm", function() { console.log("Ready!") }
```

Any suggestions on how to tweak this so it works? Or maybe another way of doing it.
[Image of network tab in devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEkQG.jpg)

Comment: this path 'video.webm' is correct ? maybe './video.webm'  or '/video.webm'

Comment: it's actually with a '/' in the code. Made mistake here

Comment: You never append the video object to the document, eg `document.body.appendChild(video)`, as for the `accept` header it is `*/*` meaning it is accepting content of any mime type, that is normal and shouldnt be a problem

Answer (score 0):

You can try `onloadeddata`. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onloadeddata.asp

Because you want it to take action when the data is loaded, not the video element itself.